# VSTS Hide Build and Release Menu

Tags: security, permissions, azure-devops

[image]

What exact security Permissions need to be denied in order to completely hide the "Build and Release" option on the top menu?
The user has Basic access level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t hide build and release menu, but you can deny all build and release permissions for that user.

1. Go to build page of a team project
2. Click Security button
3. Click Add… to add that user
4. Select that user > Deny all permissions
5. The same as release

Comment: Thanks @starian-chen-MSFT! This is what we ended doing. It does prevent the user to see all build / release but doesn't prevent them to create a new definition, which at this point I think it's a bug or something..

Comment: @stack247 Without `Edit build definition` permission, who can't save the  new build definition.

Comment: Well, what I want is to not allow certain group of users to access Build and Release, not even creating them. Creating new build definition can be assigned to another group of users.

Comment: @stack247 Without Edit build definition permission, the user can't create the new build definition, because he can't save the build definition (Can click Create, but can't save)

Comment: Yup, you are absolutely right. The user can create but can't save. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is none. Currently, all the "hubs" are visible, whether you have permission to use them or not.

See it as "an invitation to use these features in the future".